Timestamp Discrepancy Between Parent and Child Records Created in Same API Call
I am creating records for a parent(Correspondence) and a referenced model (child(IonDetail)). While saving the parent model, I am manually setting the created_at timestamp. For the child model, I am not setting it manually, as it has a default value. However, there is a time difference between the timestamps of the two records, even though they were created in the same request and the same API call.
The parent table record has a created_at timestamp of 17:18, while the child table record has a created_at timestamp of 17:12. This discrepancy is puzzling because the child record, which was created after 17:18, should logically have a greater timestamp than the parent record, not less or even slightly greater.
Even considering network latency or connection pooling, there should be only a minor difference in the timestamps. I have manually checked the database, and records are saved instantly within milliseconds and reflect immediately.
I have verified that both server and database times are synchronized and there are no transactions running or race conditions present. Can someone explain why this time discrepancy is occurring?
Here is the model for more detail model definations and here logic for saving record Logic for saving record  and here database record db_record
Solutions for the above other than manually enetering created_at in IonDetail or removing created_at from Correspondence instance while saving record
Reasons for the above problem

Does the sqlalchemy code set the default value for the created_at or is it the database? If you set one timestamp on one computer and the other on another one, there may be a difference in their system clocks which could explain it. This SO post gives some examples of how to deal with timestamps and default values.

Sqlalchemy doesn't set default value for created_at field as I have define default value for created_at is datetime.now(). Also I have already mention timestamp for db and server both are the same .

One thing that could help solve this is the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE workFlow.ion_detail and SHOW CREATE TABLE workFlow.correspondence. This way we'll know the default value in MariaDB. If the default somehow is set to the value returned by datetime.now() instead of being set as a callback, it'd explain the odd discrepancy. This reddit post seems to suggest this is the case.
